# Multiples instances of VTK (or OpenGL) in the same code

Tags: opengl, 3d, rendering, server-side-rendering, vtk

I am trying to create a rendering web server for 3D data (initially sent by web-clients), offering real-time images to the clients (using WebSockets).

My problem is with the 3D rendering instances. Using VTK, I did not found a way to keep numerous "instances" for the rendering (one for each web-client) in the same code/server. Plus, I tried OpenGL as well getting the same result. I know options as VTK.js but I need the rendering on the server-side. I am stuck!

Is there any way to render multiple 3D graphics instances using the same code? My server is on Flask, for rendering I tried VTK in C++ connected with DLLs, and VTK Python wrapper, neither doesn't work.

Comment: Rendering on the server-side is a matter of rendering to a framebuffer, retrieving into an image and sending that image to the client. If the server has only one gfx card then each image must wait for its turn to be rendered.

Comment: @Ripi2 thanks. I thought that using FBOs, however, I do not know how to "keep-alive" sessions on the server-side to provide the connection with clients. In that case, it should be establishing an OpenGL context in the server OS and handle from there... but I haven't idea how to maintain that session to send instructions to the "render window."

Comment: Epale marico ! IIUC you would like to use the same rendering code on the server to draw different views per client? Crazy idea: perhaps have a pool of GPU capable instances on the backend side, each one rendering to a FBO as a grid, then split the grid to get each client's image, so each instance could, theoretically, serve multiple clients maybe?

Comment: jajaja Henryx @higuaro, yes, the same rendering functions. Yes, your approach is the ideal scenario. However, my concern is about the blocking-thread thing using OpenGL instances + webserver sessions. In any case, I am looking for a simple and faster schema to work with!

Comment: OpenGL allows multiple contexts. It's not part of OpenGL itself, but rather the library you use to set up the OpenGL window (e.g. GLFW). You can also just render each client's frame, save the frame and send it to the client, and repeat for the next client, even if they're totally different frames - nothing in OpenGL forces one frame to be anything like the previous frame!

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yes, I am dealing with that using FBOs and keeping separate instances using a factory class. I will publish the precise result!